# Java with Yocto - no bb files matched

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm trying to generate an embedded linux image with a java oracle meta but here what I get :

```
user@user:~/poky/build$ bitbake oracle-jse-jdk-i586 
Loading cache:
100% |############################################################|
ETA:  00:00:00 Loaded 1292 entries from dependency cache. **WARNING: No
bb files matched BBFILE_PATTERN_oraclejava
'^/home/aida/poky/meta-oracle-java/'** ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES
'oracle-jse-jdk-i586' ERROR: oracle-jse-jdk-i586 was skipped: because
 it has a restricted license not whitelisted in LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST

 Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown. Summary: There was 1 ERROR
 message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Despite my bblayers.conf :

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/aida/poky/meta \
  /home/aida/poky/meta-yocto \
  /home/aida/poky/meta-oracle-java \
  /home/aida/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  "
```

I can't find where this `No bb files matched BBFILE_PATTERN` warning came from, neither then the licence problem...

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

`LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST += "oracle_java"`

to your local.conf. Review the instruction in the README file in the meta-oracle-java file.

Comment: The error indicates it isn't done correctly. Try:

`bitbake -e | grep ^LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST`

to check what the variable is actually set to. Maybe something set it to another value.

Comment: I just did and nothing happend

Comment: Well, if you run `bitbake -e | grep ^LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST` (or `bitbake -e | grep LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST`), what do you get? Unless you actually get to see that `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST` includes `oracle_java`, that's your problem.

Comment: Here what I get : 
`user@user:~/poky/build$ bitbake -e | grep ^LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST
user@user:~/poky/build$ bitbake -e | grep LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST
        whitelist = d.getVar('LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST', True)`

Answer (score 1):

My bad...

Being from France, I wrote `LICENCE_FLAGS_WHITELIST` instead of `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST`

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Good, that explains why `bitbake -e | grep LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST` didn't show you anything.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, because I've just hit the bug : in such a case you can check if another layer assigns something to the variable with '=', overwritting anything other layers/conf may have set.

Such as variable should always be appended, not assigned directly.